# Change default 192.168.174.1 of WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2 API Manager. I have deployed it but it it has static IP 192.168.174.1 . I wanted it to change this IP to my servers IP. I cant find the config file in carbon.xml or anywhere. How can I change this static IP ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Uncomment and change `<Hostname>` value of `repository/conf/carbon.xml`.

2) Search for `${carbon.local.ip}` inside `repository/conf` directory and replace it with required IP.